# Central Limit Theorem application where mean is not $0$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am given a problem that says to use the central limit theorem, where the mean of the random variable is non-zero. However the version of then central limit theorem in my text has the assumption that the mean of the random variable is $0$, so I am not sure which part I'm doing incorrectly.

**The Problem**

> Suppose that $X_1,\dots,X_{20}$ are independent random variables with density functions
>   \begin{equation*}
> f(x) = 2x, \qquad 0 \leq x \leq 1
> \end{equation*}
>   Let $S = X_1 + \cdots + X_{20}$. Use the central limit theorem to approximate $P(S \leq 10)$.

**My solution:**

By definition of $X_1,\dots,X_{20}$,
\begin{equation*}
E(X_i) = \int_{0}^{1}2x^2 = \frac{2}{3},\qquad
E(X_i^2) = \int_{0}^{1}2x^3 = \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
Var(X_i) = E(X_i^2) - E(X_i)^2 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{4}{9} = \frac{1}{18}.
\end{equation*}
By linearity and independence,
\begin{equation*}
E(S) = \sum_{i=1}^{20}E(X_i) = 20 \cdot E(X_i) = \frac{40}{3}, \qquad
Var(S) = \sum_{i=1}^{20}Var(X_i) = 20 \cdot \frac{1}{18} = \frac{10}{9}.
\end{equation*}
Then by standarding $S$ we get
\begin{equation*}
P(S \leq 10) = P\bigg(\frac{S-40/3}{\sqrt{10/9}} \leq \frac{-10}{\sqrt{10}}\bigg) \approx 1 - \Phi\big(10/\sqrt{10}\big) = 1 - 0.9992 = \boxed{0.0008}
\end{equation*}

Where $\Phi(10/\sqrt{10}) = 0.9992$ is the value of the cdf for the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$ provided from a table in the back of my textbook.

Or by the central limit theorem, let $T = S - 40/3$. Then $E(T) = 0$ and $Var(T) = Var(S)$. Note that $n=20$.
\begin{equation}
P(S \leq 10) = P(T \leq 70/3) = P\bigg(\frac{T}{\sqrt{10/9}\cdot\sqrt{20}} \leq \frac{70/3}{\sqrt{10/9}\cdot\sqrt{20}}\bigg) \approx \Phi\bigg(\frac{7}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg) = \boxed{1}
\end{equation}

I'm a bit confused, can anyone give me a hint as to what I've done wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $P(S\leq 10)\neq P(T\leq 70/3)$ since

$$
P(S\leq 10)=P(T+40/3\leq 10)=P(T\leq -10/3)
$$
and then if we standardize
$$
P(T\leq -10/3)=P\left(\frac{T}{\sqrt{10/9}}\leq\frac{-10/3}{\sqrt{10/9}}\right)=P\left(\frac{T}{\sqrt{10/9}}\leq\frac{-10}{\sqrt{10}}\right)
$$
which is the same as your initial answer.